# React hooks с кастомными callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, useeffect

как правильно подписаться на коллбэк при работе с useEffect?
Попробовал использовать useCallback, но при изменении любой из переменных (namePref, oldX, oldY) из зависимостей useCallback заново срабатывает useEffect и получается, что подписываемся на изменения (elToSub.on("click" ...)
множество раз).

```
const [oldX, SetOldX] = useState();
const [oldY, SetOldY] = useState();
const [namePref, setNamePref] = useState();

// some click callback
const clickCallback = useCallback(
 async (data) => {
   const { info, name, x, y } = data;
   SetOldX(oldX + x);
   SetOldY(oldY + y);
   setNamePref(namePref + name + info);
 },
 [namePref, oldX, oldY]
);


useEffect(() => {
 // bug is here - clickCallback is updating when some of props is changing so we remaking subscribrion;
 elToSub.on("click", clickCallback.bind(this));
}, [elToSub, clickCallback]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить стейт, основываясь на предыдущем значении, нужно в `setState` передать функцию, которая параметром принимает предыдущее значение и возвращает новое.

То есть, вместо `SetOldX(oldX + x)` нужно `SetOldX(prev => prev + x)`.

В результате коллбэк будет таким:

```
const clickCallback = async (data) => {
  const { info, name, x, y } = data;
  SetOldX(prev => prev + x);
  SetOldY(prev => prev + y);
  setNamePref(prev => prev + name + info);
}
```

Необходимости использовать `useCallback` больше нет, так как это чистая функция и можно передавать ее в зависимости в `useEffect`.

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший вариант